# hasData not able to append to paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  </head>
 <body>
   <p></p>
   <script>
     var $p = jQuery("p");
     var p = $p[0];
     $p.append(jQuery.hasData(p));
   </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

When I am executing the above code nothing is shown. But when i append empty text like **$p.append(jQuery.hasData(p) + " ");** false is being shown in page. Please let me know why this is behaving like this.

Edit : To simplify, my question is why  $p.append(false); is not showing anything but  $p.append(true); is appending true to the paragraph

Comment: Yes it appears appending boolean false, will not show up on the page http://jsfiddle.net/y1fsn3p6/ but if you append true it will show up. But when you add the empty string then for sure it will show up since it converts it to a string

Answer (score 1):

Basically when calling append function in jquery, dom manipulation will happen.
In jquery 1.10.2 during dom manipulation, before building fragments whether the contents is exist or not checking will happen,So even if you trying to append boolean value to a paragraph,it is working fine,but false does not satisfy the checking.

Answer (score 0):

Append takes a string a argument so adding an empty string to Boolean converted it to a string,
to make it work you may convert the Boolean returned to a string like this `jQuery.hasData(p).toString()`

Answer (score 0):

From jQuery [docs](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

> .append( content [, content ] )
>
> content Type: htmlString or Element or
> Array or jQuery DOM element, array of elements, HTML string, or jQuery
> object to insert at the end of each element in the set of matched
> elements.

So code like this: `jQuery.hasData(p)` return boolean **false** which isn't acceptable as content type, so when you add empty char value it converts to string and it work.

*Some investigation of jQuery src (v2.1.1 from jQuery [cdn](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js)) found this:*

'append' at line 5194 call 'domManip' with specified arguments (in our case 'true' as boolean), then at line 5363 jQuery.buildFragment called, in which at line 5070 happened this test case:

```
for ( ; i < l; i++ ) {
    elem = elems[ i ];

    if ( elem || elem === 0 ) {
```

where elems contains our 'true' as boolean. And as this case is also true, at line 5080 happened function call with nice name `context.createTextNode( elem )`. Thats because true is works and false is not. Is it help?

Comment: If false is not acceptable, then true is also not acceptable. By executing the two line below
jQuery.data(p, "text", "first");
    $p.append(jQuery.hasData(p));
I am able to get **true** as output